# how to reorganize dataframe by matches

Tags: r, dataframe

#I have the given dataframe:

```
numbers <- c(5,5,5,5,3,3,1,1,1)
outputs <- c('red','blue','blue','purple','red','yellow','red','orange','blue')
data <- data.frame(numbers,outputs)
data
```

#I want to combine all colors associated with each unique number into a row. My desired output would be:

```
numbers <- c(5,3,1)
output1 <- c('red','blue','yellow')
output2 <- c('blue','yellow','orange')
output3 <- c('blue','na','blue')
output4 <- c('purple','na','na')
data <- data.frame(numbers,output1,output2,output3,output4)
```

#What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code:

```
  numbers <- c(5,5,5,5,3,3,1,1,1)
  outputs <- c('red','blue','blue','purple','red','yellow','red','orange','blue')
  data <- data.frame(numbers,outputs)
  data
  
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(data.table)
  data %>% 
    mutate(n = rowid(numbers)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = n, values_from = outputs, names_prefix = "output")
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 3 × 5
  numbers output1 output2 output3 output4
    <dbl> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>  
1       5 red     blue    blue    purple 
2       3 red     yellow  NA      NA     
3       1 red     orange  blue    NA
```

Comment: I have one more question if you have the time. How do I get this output into its own dataframe named data2?

Comment: add data2 <- before the code like this: `data2 <- data %>% 
    mutate(n = rowid(numbers)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = n, values_from = outputs, names_prefix = "output")`. Now the output is `data2`.